# What is the lifecycle of cin and cout objects? C++

Tags: c++, stream

In C++ `cin` and `cout` are often used to read/write something to the standard I/O. They are both used as operands to the operators `<<` and `>>`. In other words they are **objects** that we use whenever we want said functionality.

Since `cin` and `cout` are **objects**, when during the lifecycle of a program are they created/initialized, so that we can use them wherever the `<iostream>` library is imported?

Comment: This should be of some help: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin "These objects are guaranteed to be initialized during or before the..."

Comment: Also this: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/Init

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> **[iostream.objects.overview]/2** The objects are constructed and the associations are established at some time prior to or during the first time an object of class `ios_base::Init` is constructed, and in any case before the body of main begins execution.<sup>294</sup> The objects are not destroyed during program execution.<sup>295</sup> The results of including `<iostream>` in a translation unit shall be as if `<iostream>` defined an instance of `ios_base::Init` with static storage duration. Similarly, the entire program shall behave as if there were at least one instance of `ios_base::Init` with static storage duration.
>
> <sup>294</sup> If it is possible for them to do so, implementations are encouraged to initialize the objects earlier than required.
>
> <sup>295</sup> Constructors and destructors for static objects can access these objects to read input from `stdin` or write output to `stdout` or `stderr`.

See also: [Nifty counter](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Nifty_Counter)